# Use a jQuery Selector as a Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I am creating a variable that stores an elements ID in the variable. I could write it like this:

```
var webappData = document.getElementById('web-app-data');
```

If I wanted to do the same using jQuery I think I would write it like this:

```
var webappData = $('#web-app-data');
```

However, when I try that it doesn't work. (Script throws an error because the variable isn't selecting the `div` with that Id.)

How would I use jQuery to select an element and store it in a variable?

Comment: It will select it just fine. It is probably your attempt to use the element that doesn't work. Could you show that code? (There's a difference between a DOM element and a jQuery selection.)

Comment: That actually does work ... but if your DOM changes then the selector now points to an element array that doesn't exist anymore (possibly). It is also going to depend on what you do with the element/variable once you have it.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?  *What* doesn't work?  Do you get an error in your console?  Does it not select the element?  Does it select the element?  We need more detail.

Comment: @Lynda Keep an eye out for your DOM changing. The following is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/wPhnA/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementById('web-app-data')` isn't the same as `$('#web-app-data')`. The later returns jQuery object, which is kind of an array of `HTMLElement` objects (only one in your case).

If you want to get `HTMLElement`, use `$('#web-app-data')[0]`. Check:

```
document.getElementById('web-app-data') === $('#web-app-data')[0]; // true
```

Comment: @Lynda See an update. Alternatively you could use `$('#web-app-data').get(0)`.

Answer (score 1):

It's ok.. Maybe something else is wrong in your code..

Example:

```
<div id="web-app-data">
    Hello
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    var webappData = $('#web-app-data');
    alert(webappData.text()); // Hello
</script>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VX5aJ/)

Answer (score 0):

Above code should work just fine. Your problem might be, that jQuery doesn't find any corresponding elements from the DOM since the element has been removed or hasn't been loaded there yet. If you try to 
`console.log($('#web-app-data'));` 
that variable, you can check if jQuery actually found anything. jQuery object should have lenght of (atleast) one if corrensponding element is indeed in DOM atm.

Answer (score 0):

That will work and you use just like it was the full JQuery selector.

```
var elm = $('#webappData');
if (elm.hasClass('someClass')) elm.removeClass('someClass');
    return;
```

Comment: Randomly change the selector won't work. Also, why use `return` if there is no function?

Comment: @Pavlo the OP ask if you could use a selector in a variable which you can I do it all the time its less typing. Also the code below was something quick to show how it worked.